# Como ejecutar una función de Python en HTML con parámetros?

Tags: html, python, django, funciones, parametros

Estoy usando Django y tengo esta función en un archivo .py

```
Users = User.objects.all()
def getCountData(idUser):
  idUser = int(idUser)
  for user in Users:
      if user.id == idUser:
        count = 0
        if ...
          count += 1
        ...
        return count
```

en el html esta asi:

```
<table>
<thead>
....
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for user in ... %}
   <tr>
     <td>
       {{ getCountData(user.id) }}
     <td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

pero me sale este error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(user.id)' from 'getCountData(user.id)'
```

ya intente con `{% ... %}` y me sale lo mismo

EL error esta en pasar el parámetro, porque si parámetros funciona (pero no necesito eso), como lo soluciono?

Answer (score 0):

Hola te paso lo que haria yo:

resumen: Basicamente transformo esa funccion en un enpoint API asi puedo llamar ese enpoint desde un codigo JS. en lo normal sigo REST pero aqui es tu eleccion.

ejemplo:

views.py

```
def getCountData(request, idUser):
  Users = User.objects.all()
  idUser = int(idUser)
  for user in Users:
      if user.id == idUser:
        count = 0
        if ...
          count += 1
        ...
        
        # Aqui haz return de la plantilla que elejiste como formato de la API con el dato counter en lo que ati te interese json, xml etcc
        return count
```

url.py

```
path('id_counter/<int:idUser>/', views.getCountData, name='id_counter')
```

html.html

```
<table>
<thead>
....
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for user in ... %}
   <tr>
     <td>
       Aqui ejecutaras el codigo js que llama el enpoint que creaste
     <td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```